# Push Notification is not display in Android Device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i follow this url http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ for display push notification in android.code is running without any error but when i send message from server it not showing on device and also not showing notification

Comment: Do you have some code to review? What did you implement so far?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: i use same code given in above url.just changed Sender id and Google Key Id.